# Help simplifying an equation of motion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I have a weird equation of motion that I am trying to simplify (it kind of reminds me of Brans-Dicke, but with a direct coupling between a field and Ricci Scalar):
\begin{equation}
\left[R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}\Box-\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\right]\phi=8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}-R\partial_\mu \sigma\partial_\nu \sigma
\end{equation}

The relation between $\sigma$ and $\phi$ is $\phi\equiv g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha \sigma\partial_\beta \sigma$. Ultimately, my question is that I would like to be able to simplify the above equation of motion such that it only has $\phi$ in it (e.g. get rid of $\sigma$), but I am out of ideas.

While $\phi$ and $\sigma$ are not completely independent of each other, the fact that I may think of $\phi$ as the trace of the matrix $\partial_\mu\sigma\partial^\nu\sigma$ means that I can't write the last term in terms of $\phi$ only.

Are there any approaches that might help me write the final term in terms of $\phi$ only? I've tried contracting with $\nabla^\mu\nabla^\nu$, contracting with null vectors $k^\mu k^\nu$, but no luck.

Or is this impossible to simplify further? And help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. (Yes, this equation of motion is wacky and likely can be ruled out fairly easily, but I would still like to know if it's possible to rewrite without an explicit dependence on $\sigma$.)

Comment: The dimension is $D=4$?

Comment: yes (3 spacial and 1 temporal)

Comment: What is $T_{\mu\nu}$? Your equation suggests that $T^\mu{}_\mu = 0$. Is that useful?

Comment: It's the usual stress energy tensor (right now this is calculated in vacuum, so you're correct that $T=0$). I'm mostly wondering if anyone had any ideas of an approach that I can take to trying to solve it (key word being try.....I am out of ideas). =)

Comment: Why not just contract it with $g^{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: @Slereah, you end up with T = 0 (which doesn't help the goal of eliminating $\sigma$ from the equation of motion).